# JCheckBoxMenuItem stays checked when switching tabs

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a pretty basic interface of a chromotagram viewer. In the menu I allow the user to reverse the viewer with a JCheckboxMenuItem. Functionally, it does exactly what its supposed to do. My interface allows for multiple chromatograms to be open at once. I will post a few example pictures as I get to my question.

[image]

Above I have one tab opened and have yet to reverse the chromatogram.

[image]

Above I have clicked the option and it worked.

[image]

Here is my issue. If I open another tab and move to it, the option is still checked even though I have yet to click that button. The easy way out would be just to make it a normal button but I just want to know if there is a way that each tabbed could keep track of if its been reversed yet. Would this require multiple instances of the button itself? If anybody has any suggestions, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a listener for the tabs switching and updating the menu item state? In that case you only need one instance of the menu item.

Comment: I believe that the issue is that the jcheckboxmenuitem is not associated with the tab, but rather with the top-level window, and there is only one of them with this window. If you need one specific for the tab, then perhaps you will need to add a JMenuBar to the components displayed by the tab -- allowing each tab to have its own jcheckboxmenuitem item.

Comment: This would require creating a JPanels that uses BorderLayout to hold your graphic display in the BorderLayout.CENTER position and the new JMenuBar in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(centralPara.getNumOpen() > 1){
    centralPanel = centralList.get(centralPara.getCurrentFrame());
    JCheckBoxMenuItem reverseItem = centralPara.getReverseItem();
    boolean reversed = centralPanel.getReversed();
    reverseItem.setSelected(reversed);
 }
```

in my tab change listener I check to see that we have atleast more than one tab open. if so get the frame we are currently viewing and the top level menu item. Force it be be selected if that the current view frame is selected, or else force it be unselected.